# Code First: Optional One to One Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, fluent

I have two entity models, Series and Fixture. A series may have a fixture and a fixture may have a series. Here are simplified version of both entities.

Series.cs

```
public class Series
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? FixtureId { get; set; }
    public virtual Fixture Fixture { get; set; }
}
```

Fixture.cs

```
public class Fixture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? SeriesId { get; set; }
    public virtual Series Series { get; set; }
}
```

and then my fluent is as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Series>()
            .HasOptional(a => a.Fixture)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(a => a.Series);
```

I dont know if I need to mark my properties with certain annotations or if my fluent config is incorrect.

With this particular example I am getting the following error when I try to run update-database -verbose

The index 'IX_Series_Id' is dependent on column 'Series_Id'.
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN Series_Id failed because one or more objects access this column.

Current migration code:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropIndex("dbo.Series", new[] { "FixtureId" });
        RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Fixture", name: "FixtureId", newName: "Series_Id");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Fixture", "Series_Id");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropIndex("dbo.Fixture", new[] { "Series_Id" });
        RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Fixture", name: "Series_Id", newName: "FixtureId");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Series", "FixtureId");
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the migration code to your post? I assume the order of events is incorrect. The index should be dropped before the column.

Comment: Ill update the OP with the migration code now.

Comment: Its updated now

Comment: It does not look like you are running a Drop Column command to cause that error.  Is that the complete/correct Migration?

Comment: I had made some changes in the mean time, so the migration code could be off. When I add migration im getting a complete database tables creation